# How to change the text format of a title of a web part

Tags: 2013

I want to be able to change the title of a web part

Example of current title: Announcements

Example of what I want: ***Announcements***

I would also like to be able to change the font size and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below style to the page you want this style.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-titleText {
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

You will see title as follow

[image]

Comment: I am talking about a web part not a page. Like one of the widgets that you can add to a content editor (e.g. calendar, announcements, discussions, etc.)

Comment: I mean page is a web part page. You need to add a Script Editor Web Part and add above CSS enclosed with `<style type="text/css"></style>`

Comment: I can add a script editor web part to my home page and it will affect the other web parts in the content editor?

Comment: Yes. If you want for only one web part then you need to find out web part id using browser developer tool. Then the css class will change to `#you_webpart_id .ms-webpart-titleText`

Comment: I added the script editor web part to the same content editor and added the style but when I save it just displays the style as text and nothing happens to the titles of the other web parts.

Comment: You need to enclose above css under `<style type="text/css"></style>`.

Comment: see updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60145/discussion-between-mdomin45-and-venkat-konjeti).