# How to change the title of a Content Editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the title of a Content Editor webpart to bold?

Greetings, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the format code (CSS) directly in the Content Editor web part.

Here is a sample script:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-titleText {
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Test outcome:

[image]

Reference:
[How to change the text format of a title of a web part.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217661/how-to-change-the-text-format-of-a-title-of-a-web-part)

Answer (score 1):

That depends. In SharePoint on premises, you can use custom CSS to change the style for web part titles, which would affect all web parts, not just the CEWP. In SharePoint online, the CSS is a lot harder to manipulate.

If you only want to change the appearance of a single web part title, any custom CSS would be overkill. Just hide the web part title and place static text on the page above the web part.